# angular js, accessibility , tables, keyboard arrow keys navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyboard, accessibility

I got an old angular js application and my mission is to fix accessibilty problems. I have a table that includes radio buttons within the cells and I need to navigate between them using the arrow up and down keys.

I already have a method that deals with this issue and its working fine until i test it using screen reader (NVDA)

What happens is for some reason the SR cause the method to be ignored 
and causes the table to lose its focus.

the only way that I managed to make it work is by setting the table with `role="application"`.
but from what I have been reading so far it is wrong to use it in this case

This is a sample of one of the cells :

```html
    <td class="scheduleLineCell" style="text-align: center;">
         <input type="radio" 
                class="btnRadio ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched ng-dirty" 
                aria-describedby="" 
                value="126" data-ng-model="selectedIdList[childSchedule.gridIndex]" 
                data-ng-key-press="scheduleKeyPress" 
                data-ng-grid-index="0" 
                xng-focus="isFocusOnStationButton == false &amp;&amp; 
                isFocusOnMapButton == false &amp;&amp; ScheduleLine.Id == 
                selectedIdList[search.currentScheduleGridIndex]" name="2096">
    </td>
```

Comment: Your question is too vague to address. What "method" are you trying to implement? And how/why is it not working? What is the expected vs actual behavior? You'll likely get better answers here if you focus on examples of the rendered HTML and less on the angular code.

Comment: The behavior that is working without the screen reader is simply moving the focus from one radio button to the other and of course selecting it ( each of them is in different row cell. The thing is that working with SR for some reason disables this functionality

Comment: It's still very difficult for me to understand what you're trying to do and what's not working. It might be helpful if you could post the entire HTML table. The way that keyboard interaction should work is that you should be able to `tab` into radio button groups. Once focus is on a group, you should be able to use the up/down arrow keys to move between individual buttons. This is the standard behavior that is expected among users of assistive technology. There is no expectation that arrows would move between groups. https://www.w3.org/wiki/RadioButton

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a working example on here or on JSfiddler?

Off the top of my head I can say this.

1. You should not put controls in tables or uses tables for design purposes.

   a. If you have an enter data row make it from "div"s

   b. Remember screen readers repeat table headers a lot!
2. JAWS and NVDA does mess with a screens JSEvents and get us a example page to help
3. (AngularJS) Refactor the control back to a component or directive and see if that helps.

       a. e.g. 
   `<custom-radio-button ng-value="val" aria-checked="true"></custom-radio-button>`

Comment: i know the current structure is wrong but i am not planning on changing it for now, any way i found the solution for my problem - adding role="presentation" to the warping table. not 100% sure why it works but it does... if any one can explain what made this solution work please explain

Comment: https://timwright.org/blog/2016/11/19/difference-rolepresentation-aria-hiddentrue/
I think this can help, to the screen reader you have changed the structure of the page so it can find stuff.